# Large to medium size e-Ink Display for prototyping

Tags: prototyping, display, e-ink, oled

I have been doing research in finding various raw screens for prototyping, stuff like e-ink, color e-ink and OLED screens.  Then I saw this earlier post: [Gumstix with an e-ink screen](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13157/gumstix-with-an-e-ink-screen)

So after one year since the original post by @tjameson, has anyone find a place to get e-ink screens that are larger than 6 inches?  For what I am trying to do, I really need 6 to 11 inches screens.

Comment: Probably the cheapest place to get 1 to prototype with is a Kindle/Nook or other eReader.